# Routes on laravel 8.1.0

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

Hi everyone I have a problem with laravel 8.1.0.
At the moment of wanting to create the routes in the web.php file
with the following code I get an error stating that the controller does not exist

web.php file

```
Route::get('/home/','HomeController@index');
```

I get the error "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist."

I have seen in the laravel documentation that version 8 has different calls for the controllers than the previous versions, I have applied the changes suggested by the documentation, however everything remains the same

I have added the following code in the file routeserviceprovider.php in app\providers

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
->namespace($this->namespace)  //inside $this-> routes (function ()
->namespace($this->namespace)  //inside Route::prefix('api')
```

According to the laravel documentation this should work, however I keep getting the same error.
"Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist."

I have tried adding `use App\Http\Controllers;` in web.php file, but I have the same error message
I have tried using `Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');` and `Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);` but I have the same message error

web.php complete file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/persona/','PersonaController@index')->name('per','persona');
Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/home/','HomeController@index');
```

routeservicesprovider.php complete file

```
<?php

namespace sisVentas\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * If specified, this namespace is automatically applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';  //agregado

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)  //agregado
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)  //agregado
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60);
        });
    }
}
```

My homecontroller file

```
<?php

namespace sisVentas\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

The problem is the same with all the routes that I try to access.
I have lost a whole day trying to repair the routes, but I get the error of not finding them, I would like to know how to do it, thank you very much for reading this far :)

Comment: Can you show your HomeController?

Comment: May be a silly question, but does that controller actually exist? Does it have the correct namespace on top and is the namespace root correctly set in your composer.json ?

Comment: @aynber I have updated the post with the homecontroller included

Comment: @apokryfos sorry, but when I search the composer.json file the search engine shows me dozens of files

Comment: I was talking about the one in the root of your porject. Also since you're not using the the standard app namespace you `php artisan app:name sisVentas`

Comment: Your namespace is `sisVentas\Http\Controllers`, not `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: @aynber ok, I have changed the namespace line for "protected $namespace = 'sisventas\http\controllers';"  but I have the same error

Comment: Route name should be a [string](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L821).

Comment: @Tpojka excuse me, where?

Comment: You have this `->name('per','persona');` - should be one string instead.

Comment: `sisventas\http\controllers` is still the wrong name. Note the name is case sensitive so it should be `sisventas\Http\Controllers` in addition can you share the segment called `psr-4` in your `composer.json` in your root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace is wrong.The app is searching for this controller in **App\Http\Controller** but your controllers namespace is **sisVentas\Http\Controllers**.

Depending on your directory structure if your root folder is *sisVentas*
you should use

```
    protected $namespace = 'sisVentas\Http\Controllers';
```

Or if your root is *App* you should change your controller and providers namespace to

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

not require such kind of function in routeservicesprovider.php

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';   x

**please try this definitely  will work..**

Route::get('/home','App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\homeController@index');

write complete path.

and no need write to call top lavel

Comment: Please include code blocks in `` (backticks). It will be easier for users to identify the code block.

ex ```js (your content)  ```